# Is there a way to select all Storyboard segues in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am approaching the final steps of my first app, and I am realizing that I didn't change the default storyboard segue for any of my (too many to count) segues. Is there a way to select all of them and/or set all of them to one of the other default segue options?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you actually can drag-select segues and set them all to one value. You just can't command-click.